# Is a question about a proposed law on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Currently there is in Spain a political initiative to give "legal personality" to a lagoon (Mar Menor) that has ecological issues.

My question would not be about the political process, proponents and/or detractors, but how it would affect legal actions if it were approved, but since it is still not in force and subject to many possible changes I am not sure if the question would be on-topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is a question about a proposed law on-topic?

Yes. A tentative statute or a preliminary legislative intent might contain enough substance to allow for an assessment of its adequacy and how compatible (if at all) it would be with the country's Constitution, other legislation, or public policy.

In fact, law proposals typically undergo scrutiny in which jurists/legal researchers identify *in their professional capacity* (and thus aside from political and economical considerations) potential issues with an initiative or bill/draft that "*is still not in force and subject to many possible changes*". The fact that contributors on a public website like LawSE are not necessarily jurists or legal researchers makes no difference as to whether the question being addressed is on-topic or off-topic.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as long as:

1. It's a specific question, as opposed to something overly broad like "what would be the effects of this proposed law?".
2. You can point to specific proposed legal text that someone could interpret. Sometimes a proposed law doesn't have proposed text available, so any questions about it would be purely speculative as to what lawmakers *might* enact.  A question like that would be off-topic.

But generally, as long as it makes it clear that it's about the proposed version (and *which* proposed version), I don't think there's a need to wait until the law is enacted to ask about it.